# Android app does not work after latest update

Tags: android, sdk, crash, updates, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I have been developing an app for a project and recently I just updated my Android system from 6.0 to 6.0.1. After that my app would just crash when I tried to run it. I have git for version control so I am definitely sure that it worked on Android 6.0.0. I've set the target sdk level to be 21, 22 and 23 and none of them worked.

Here is my log, but there is no error message for the app:

02-14 17:30:31.287 16570-16570/com.dji.FPVDemo D/FPVController: try to load libdjivideo.so

02-14 17:30:31.294 16570-16570/com.dji.FPVDemo W/linker: /data/app/com.dji.FPVDemo-2/lib/arm/libdjivideo.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.

02-14 17:30:31.309 16570-16570/com.dji.FPVDemo D/CallBack: dji.sdk.api.mediacodec.DJIVideoDecoder@23a4c67

02-14 17:30:31.312 16570-16570/com.dji.FPVDemo I/api: connect to Inspire

02-14 17:30:31.312 16570-16570/com.dji.FPVDemo D/DJIProductManager: type=litchiS last=None

02-14 17:30:31.331 16570-16570/com.dji.FPVDemo I/api: connect to Inspire out

02-14 17:30:31.332 16570-16570/com.dji.FPVDemo I/data Receiver: set need packed =false

02-14 17:30:31.359 16570-16620/com.dji.FPVDemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

02-14 17:30:31.415 16570-16608/com.dji.FPVDemo I/onLoad: loaded onLoad.cpp :JNI_OnLoad() go to end

02-14 17:30:31.415 16570-16608/com.dji.FPVDemo D/GroudStation: load lib suc

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the DJI SDK is having problems with api 23. I am also doing a project with the DJI drones and my app was working perfectly with my nexus 6 with android 6.0.0. api 22. As soon as I updated it to android 6.0.1 api 23 it had problems. You just have to wait it out until DJI updates their SDK and makes it compatible with the new android updates. Until then just backup your android phone and downgrade it back to api 22, android 6.0.0 and continue to develop your app. All the best.